# How to run cron job on mysql database through php

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am new to `cron` and I do not know how to work it and I have researched everywhere, but I am confused

I have a mysql database which is connected to php and it is on a website which is called `ytable.php.`

Within that php file, I have a for loop which needs running every hour in order to retrieve new information. However, I am not sure what to do in order to do this.

I know I have to write `0 * * * *` somewhere in the coding.

Most of the answers on this website tells how the `* * * * *` work, but I am not interested intuit because I already understand that bit of the `cron` job.

**Do you either:**

put the command in a text file and write `<?php exec(whatevertextfile.txt) ?>` in the file itself?

OR

Everyone has been telling me to open up Terminal(Mac) and put it in `crontab -e`, but I do not know what to write when I get there.

Can you not run a cron job from a php file as I find it easier to edit compared to Terminal.

Please help.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/ crontab -e is quite simple. Make sure you have the right privs when creating the cronjob or else you're going to get some odd errors associated with them.

Comment: crontab is a standard service on linux that is used for scheduling tasks. it doesn't have anything to do with PHP. You use `crontab -e` from the console to edit the configuration of the service (i.e. what to run and when).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

You need to run a php file through cron job.

```
in your terminal...

user > crontab -e

0 * * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php  -f  /<absolute path of file>/cron_summary_sales.php
```

< /opt/lampp/bin/php > this is PHP path, as I use LAMPP,
You use appropriate path for your PHP setup in your MAC. you also have to make sure how to run PHP from MAC terminal.

save it.

---

For mac, 
I think you should do,

```
0 * * * *  php  /<absolute path of file>/cron_summary_sales.php

OR

0 * * * *   /<absolute path of dir>  php  cron_summary_sales.php
```

Comment: The error 'E348: No string under cursor' comes up and I can't type anything except '/' in the crontab -e

Comment: hit ESC and it will take you out of a *nix shortcut operand

Comment: Do it like, you do with VIM editor, press I, then type, then press ESC, then :wq

Comment: How do you find out your php path. I'm still a noob

Comment: After an hour, check the reflations that your PHP makes in your database, or first try to run a dummy cron job that inserts something in database with < */2 * * * *  these runs cron job every 2 minute >. then after properly testing, run your original cron ! Simple ! Also try to run a PHP from the terminal first, so you can know if any errors are there or not ! because sometimes PHP file runs fine from web-browser but it has some issues if you run it from the terminal !

Comment: is it helpful ? then plz vote up, as it took significant time to explain !

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal:

```
#lists current jobs setup
someUser~>crontab -l

#let's you edit/create jobs
someUser~>crontab -e
```

Once you open the file:

```
 * * * * * /usr/blah/hooray python someFile.py
```

Then hit ESC . type ":x" <-- short hand for write\quit

It's best to setup your cronjob for a few minutes from when you create it to see it in action. You can use the >> somefile.txt to log what's going on

Comment: It says "E748: No previously used register" when i try to write something in crontab -e

Comment: ??!! You're probably not using vi correctly. hit the "i" key to insert or alter the document. **Sounds like a recording issue. or some macro running. Once complete hit ESC

Comment: ++Just would like to add knowing VI is a HUGE plus on the resume so it would behoove you to learn it.